# Creating a 2 level Multi Index

Tags: multi-index

I'd like to create a multi index where: the first column is 'ID', the second column is Revenue and EBITDA, and the 5 different dates as columns.

Please see image of the dataframe attached. Thanks guys

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rit5j.png

Comment: Please add much more information, no image is attached, what language are you using, what code have you attempted, what specifically are you having trouble doing? We cant help without more info.

Comment: Apologies, see image attached and using python. I haven't attached the code as its pulling data off Bloomberg API which I'm guessing isn't accessible to most people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it eventually:

```py
dataframe = dataframe.pivot_table(index=['ID'],values= ['Revenue','EBITDA'],columns='Date').stack(0,1)
```